# Limit on number of planes one can get every day in Sky Force 2014

Tags: android, sky-force-2014

In [Sky Force 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.skyforcehd&hl=en), one can get new planes by watching 30-second advertisements, at least on Android. One day I seemed to have reached some limit, as the screenshot below shows. Is this limit the same every day?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm you can only do this so many times per day, and it's the same number of times per day. No way to get around it, this limit is embedded in the script itself not by their servers.

I think it's to avoid abuse of the system.